# What is the asymptotic runtime complexity of my code?

Tags: performance, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Heres my code below, i'm trying to find out the asymptotic runtime complexity of my code but im not sure

```
public static int myAlgorithm(List<Integer> myList) {
 if (myList.isEmpty()) {
 return 0;
    } 
 
Collections.sort(myList); // Can assume the sort algorithm is merge sort 

int sum = 0; 
int max = myList.get(myList.size() - 1); 
for (int item : myList) {
 int diff = Math.abs(max - item);
 sum = sum + diff; 
    } 
return sum; 
}
```

Comment: No assumptions necessary; the complexity of `Collections.sort` should be documented.

Comment: Note that your function is less efficient than it could be. Sorting is a terrible way to find the largest item in a collection. You can find that simply be scanning the list O(n) time, rather than sorting in O(n lg n) time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the sort you're using is merge sort, the asymptomatic running time of the algorithm is O(NlogN)

The most complex step is the sort step.

The code after that is approximately O(N); 1 loop and 1 passthrough when looking for max.